# How use compress-images?

Tags: node.js, image-compression, imagemin

How use compress-images?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-images

Gif image was - `4.1mb`;

Gif image became - `4.2mb`;

Gif image after compression is obtained more size than before. Why?

I try:

```
compress_images('src/img/**/*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,svg,gif}', 'build/img/', {compress_force: false, statistic: true, autoupdate: true}, false,
                                                {jpg: {engine: 'mozjpeg', command: ['-quality', '60']}},
                                                {png: {engine: 'pngquant', command: ['--quality=0-20']}},
                                                {svg: {engine: 'svgo', command: '--multipass'}},
                                                {gif: {engine: 'gifsicle', command: false}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell why the size increased. I guess the algorithm doesn't work as we want it to work with default parameters.

To compress the gif you have to look at the [gifsicle manual](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/man.html) and find the correct parameters for your use case. You can for example reduce the colors or the size of the image:

`--colors 16`

`--scale 0.7`

Supply them as arguments to the command field.

You can also change to another alogrithm such as `giflossy` or `gif2webp`.